# How do I edit a comment if the ID is not passed via the URL - Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So this is my partial:

```
<% upload_ids = comment.uploads.collect {|u| u.id }%>
<li>
    <div class="details">
        <span class="comment_name"><%= (comment.user.username).capitalize %></span> said
        <div class="comment-edit-icons">
            <% link_to(edit_comment_path) do %>
                <span class="icon edit-icon" title="Edit"> </span>
            <% end %>
            <span class="icon destroy-icon" data-destroy-title="Delete <%= comment.id %>?" data-destroy-url="<%= comment_path(comment) %>" title="Delete"> </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uploads">
        <% comment.stage.uploads.each do |upload| %>
            <div class="upload-image<% if upload_ids.include?(upload.id) %> selected-image<% end %>" title="<%= upload.name %>"><%= image_tag(upload.image.url(:thumb))%></div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
        <div class="body">
            <%= comment.body %><br />
            <span class="timestamp"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.updated_at) %> ago</span>
        </div>
</li>
```

I tried `edit_comment_path` but that doesn't work because the URL has the ID for another model, not the comments.

The partial that calls this looks like this:

```
<ul class="comments-list">
<% comments.order("created_at DESC").each do |comment| %>
    <%= render :partial => "comments/show", :locals => {:comment => comment }%>
<% end %>
```

What I would like to do is have the `span` with title 'Edit' be the link to editing that particular comment.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, the following should work as you describe:

```
edit_comment_path(comment)
```

The ID comes from the passed ActiveRecord object, in this case a comment, rather than from the current URL.

Comment: Douglas, what happen is if I wanted to do the delete. I tried `delete_comment_path(comment)` and `destroy...` and neither work. Thoughts ? I also want to do it in the same structure of the link_tag helper block.

Comment: To delete a comment you want to use the DELETE HTTP verb, along with the show URL for the object. `link_to(comment_path(comment), :method => :delete) do …`